# Pandas ASSIGN function - use dynamic column name in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pseudocode:

```
for col in df.columns:
     df.assign('Test_' + str(col) = 1)
```

This code won't work. But how do I use a string in the assign operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `**` and do:

```
df.assign(**{
    "Test_"+col: 1 for col in df.columns
    })

   col1  col2  col3  col4  Test_col1  Test_col2  Test_col3  Test_col4
0     1     0     1     0          1          1          1          1
1     0     0     1     0          1          1          1          1
2     0     1     1     0          1          1          1          1
3     1     0     0     0          1          1          1          1
4     0     0     1     1          1          1          1          1
```

Setup:

```
{'col1': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'col2': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'col3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'col4': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}}
```

Comment: What is that operator called **{}?

Comment: @bananaboy That's dictionary unpacking – https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html